# Add Missing Dates to Time Series ID's in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[66991,'2020-06-01',2],
                   [66991,'2020-06-02',1],
                   [66991,'2020-07-03',1],
                   [44551,'2020-10-01',1],
                   [66991,'2020-12-05',7],
                   [44551,'2020-12-05',5],
                   [66991,'2020-12-01',1],
                   [66991,'2021-01-08',3]],columns=['ID','DATE','QTD'])
```

How can I add the the months (in which `QTD` is zero), to each `ID` ? (Ideally I would like for the column `BALANCE` and `CC` to keep the previous value, for each `ID`, on the added rows but this not not stricly necessary as I am more interested on the `QTD` and `VAL` columns).

I thought about maybe resampling the data by month for each `ID` on a data frame and then merge that data frame to the one above. Is this a good implementation? Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Should end up similar to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[66991,'2020-06-01',2],
                   [66991,'2020-06-02',1],
                   [66991,'2020-07-03',1],
                   [66991,'2020-08-01',0],
                   [66991,'2020-09-01',0],
                   [66991,'2020-10-01',0],
                   [44551,'2020-10-01',1],
                   [44551,'2020-11-05',0],
                   [66991,'2020-11-01',0],
                   [66991,'2020-12-05',7],
                   [44551,'2020-12-05',5],
                   [66991,'2020-12-01',1],
                   [66991,'2021-01-08',3]],columns=['ID','DATE','QTD'])
```

Comment: **Please share some code**. What have you tried so far? What is the error? Can you show a sample of the input and desired output (in code)?

Comment: Just added the code (simpler version). Until now honestly I have had no success. I looked at answers online but they don't give a solution that fits my problem because it is not for each `ID` but a general one.

Comment: Not a `scikit-learn`, `numpy`, or `jupyter-notebook` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a range of dates by ID using `pd.date_range`, then create a `pd.MultiIndex` so you can do a `reindex`:

```
s = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, x) for i, j in df.groupby("ID")
                               for x in pd.date_range(min(j["DATE"]), max(j["DATE"]), freq="MS")],
                              names=["ID", "DATE"])

df = df.set_index(["ID", "DATE"])

print (df.reindex(df.index|s, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .groupby(["ID", pd.Grouper(key="DATE", freq="M")], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda i: i[i["QTD"].ne(0)|(len(i)==1)])
         .droplevel(0))

       ID       DATE  QTD
0   44551 2020-10-01    1
1   44551 2020-11-01    0
3   44551 2020-12-05    5
4   66991 2020-06-01    2
5   66991 2020-06-02    1
7   66991 2020-07-03    1
8   66991 2020-08-01    0
9   66991 2020-09-01    0
10  66991 2020-10-01    0
11  66991 2020-11-01    0
12  66991 2020-12-01    1
13  66991 2020-12-05    7
15  66991 2021-01-08    3
```

Comment: How can I drop the duplicated ones? For example, if an `ID` has a `QTD` bigger than zero on a month, I want to discard the just added zero entry.

Comment: That is just some basic duplicates dropping. I have added in the above.